# AWS CDK - How do I create ECR repo conditionally

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, ncurses-cdk

Using the AWS CDK STACK how do I check and create a ECR repository if it does not exist. In other words how I do check if the ECR repository with a specific name(for example "TestRepository") already exists.

The code to create new rep:

```
 this.TestRepository = new Repository(this, "TestRepository", new RepositoryProps
        {
            RepositoryName = "TestRepository"
        });
```

When I try to deploy the stack again(redeploy) it shows error repository with the name already exists

So in order to avoid this error how I do check if the ECR repository with a specific name(for example "TestRepository") already exists...I am looking for something like UPSERT

Answer (score 0):

I know to handle this scenario with Terraform but not used CDKTF but seems like this one should work. Please refer https://loige.co/create-resources-conditionally-with-cdk